# Deligne's internal characterisation of Tannakian categories - glueing of algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, tannakian-category, symmetric-monoidal-categories

I am currently reading the proof of Deligne's internal characterization of Tannakian categories (Thm. 7.1) in [Deligne: *Catégories tannakiennes*](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/60_categoriestanna.pdf).

My question is similar to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/237583/delignes-theorem-on-the-characterisation-of-tannakian-categories).

Given a cocomplete tensor category $\mathcal{C}$ the paper shows that for every object $X\in \mathcal{C}$ there is a commutative ring $A_X\in \mathcal{C}$ such that $A_X\otimes X\cong A_X^{\oplus\text{dim}X}$, where this is an isomorphism of $A_X$-modules.

However, in the final stage of the proof, it is claimed that there is a commutative ring $B\in \mathcal{C}$ such that $X\otimes B \cong B^{\oplus \text{dim} X}$ holds for all $X\in \mathcal{C}$.

I fail to see how the first statement implies the second. The only idea I have is to consider the coproduct $\bigoplus_{X\in \mathcal{C}} A_X$ over all the $A_X$. But I am not sure if this would even be a commutative ring in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: You want to take a set of generators of $\mathcal C$ and then take the colimit of all tensor products of  $A_X$ for finitely many $X$ in $\mathcal C$. This involves using the unit of the algebras to define the maps in this colimit.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Do you mean the following: Let $S$ be a set of tensor generators of $\mathcal{C}$. Then set $A := \text{colim}_{J\subseteq S,~J~\text{finite}} \bigotimes_{X'\in J} A_X'$?.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm thinking.